# promise all mongoose find return incomplete value

Tags: javascript, mongoose, promise, async-await

I try everything to make a promise loop form two queries. I make one query that call the other query. But the retuned values will only return the first query. I can not combine those two. Here is my code

```
 exports.beschikbaarheid = function (req, res, next) {
  const { leverancier, start, eind } = req.body;
  Categorie.find({
    leverancier: leverancier,
  })
    .exec()
    .then((result) => {
      return Promise.all(
        result.map(async (record) => {
          const voor = await Voorraad.find({
            categorie: record._id,
          }).exec();
          record.voorraad = voor;
          return record;
        })
      ).then((results) => {
        res.json({
          results,
        });
      });
    })
};
```

When I return records it will only return the query of the "Categorie.find" When I return only "voor" it will return alle values form "Voorraad" and also by group from "Categorie", but the value does nog contact any data from the "Categorie"

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you should use [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) instead. Something like this:

```
Categorie.aggregate([
  {$match: {leverancier: leverancier}},
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "voorraads", // collection of model Voorraad
      localField: "_id",
      foreignField: "categorie",
      as: "voorraad"
    }
  }
])
```